# Cannot add objects to settings.json for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following for my localsettings.json file in an Azure Function

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ConnectionString": "...",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage":
      "...",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "event-bus-connection": "..."
  }
}
```

This works fine

Howver, I now need to add more into here

```
 "JwtIssuerOptions": {
      "Issuer": "...",
      "Audience": "...",
      "SecretKey": "...",
      "ExpirationInMinutes": 3600
    },
```

As soon as I add this within Values the function wont start:

**Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json.**

How can I get this to work?

Paul

Comment: I believe localseettings.json does not support object notation for defining the settings. What you can do is define as a key with `:` notation like `"JwtIssuerOptions:Issuer":...., "JwtIssuerOptions:Audience":...., ` And now using `JwtIssuerOptions` string literal you can bind to config for options binding.

Comment: Thanks this works, please can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Sure, let me add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localseettings.json` does not support object notation for defining the settings. What you can do is define as a key with `:` notation like "JwtIssuerOptions:Issuer":....,

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ConnectionString": "...",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage":"...",
    "JwtIssuerOptions:Issuer": "...",
    "JwtIssuerOptions:Audience": "...",
    "JwtIssuerOptions:SecretKey": "...",
    "JwtIssuerOptions:ExpirationInMinutes": 3600,
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "event-bus-connection": "..."
  }
}
```

And now using `JwtIssuerOptions` string literal you can bind to config for options binding

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<JwtAuthorizationOptions>()
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
    {
       configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").Bind(settings);
    });
```